# Jackson Json parsing exception for hibernate class

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I'm using Spring 3 + JPA 2 (hibernate Impl) + Spring MVC's contentNegotiationResolver based on Json media type and got the following exception stack trace is thrown while leveraging Spring framework's 
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView

*

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain:..... )
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider$1.serialize(StdSerializerProvider.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:268)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:118)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$AsArraySerializer.serialize(ContainerSerializers.java:111)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:296)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:224)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:925)
    at org.springframewor
```

*

The solution provided in the below thread is not working (using Json AutoDetect) doesnt work for me.

[Strange Jackson exception being thrown when serializing Hibernate object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362104/strange-jackson-exception-being-thrown-when-serializing-hibernate-object)

Providing Json AutoDetect and explicitly providing Json property annotation on getter method is not working - it still parses all the attributes. Also I've succeeded by avoiding certain attributes of JPA Entity class using @JsonIgnore which is kind of recursive or parent/child relation in nature. I've also tried detaching the entity class but no luck.

From my entity class, all the Jackson parser need to do is parse some three simple String attributes  and rest of the attributes is marked with @JsonIgnore

Please let me know if any of you faced similar issue and resolved it.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277439/lazy-loadng-error-in-json-serializer